# Best NoSQL DB structure for score accumulating website with users

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, backend

I've done lots of relational databases, but brand new to the NoSQL concepts.

I'm currently building a website to consolidate highscores for various video games, where each user can submit a new score daily. I also want to keep the history of past scores submitted by users.

In classical relational databases I would probably have 3 tables (Users, Games, Highscores), but have no idea how to do something similar in NoSQL.

For reference I intend on using DynamoDB.

From my understanding this could maybe be accomplished by just using one large users table? That stores highscores on a game basis for each user? This seems like it will be MASSIVE. But then my question here is, if I need to query just for a list of games, this seems incredibly inefficient. I definitely need to learn more, but if anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be great! Thank you

Comment: Have you seen this AWS's [Amazon DynamoDB: Gaming use cases and design patterns](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/amazon-dynamodb-gaming-use-cases-and-design-patterns/) article?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't using NoSQL database that way. Denormalization works the same way for NoSQL. NoSQL lasts of relationship between tables and constraints, but could scale horizontally. And NoSQL could be schemaless.

In case you want to use DynamoDB you must understand usage of your tables because you can't do any query you want. You can do only query against Partition and Sort Key and Full Table Scan with filtering results (and it's extremely costly). Also you can use DynamoDB streams to do any business logic against table updates.

DynamoDB provides a lot of different features, but most of them is not your case.